# How to add notification in webview?

Tags: android, webview, notifications, push-notification, android-webview

I have created a webview app which working is perfectly fine with a website say xyz.com

The app is made for small scale purpose and for personal use. (Not uploaded in play store)

Generally  when I change some content in the website -  Index.html(say) the app also gets update as it loads the updated url.

I want to create a notification that whenever I change the content user gets a notification in their notification bar say (today event - abc ) and when they click that notification it opens the app to see what got updated.

How to create such notifications?

Comment: Hey, I have similar requirements, so did you able to find the solution? If yes then please share it with me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to first register your user and get the gcm registration id and save it on your server. Then you can implement notification system present in android like this http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html
Whenever you change your content just send a notification to all the user base and your work is done. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can add bootstrap modal in index.html page. and add content on that model